# Code-changes in dependencies are not updated automatically

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm having some dependencies in my projects which I'm including in my **pom.xml**:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mahlzeit</groupId>         
        <artifactId>mz-data-model</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>mz-web-shared</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, my problem is that changes in the code of these projects are not visible to my web server when I'm running it.

I always have to run

```
mvn clean install
```

in `mz-web-shared/` and `mz-data-model/` such that the jar files are getting compiled and the repository updated.

Why do I have to do that and how can I make this work without me having to run `mvn clean install` manually in my dependencies?

Comment: Deleting previous question (that I'm sure existed although I don't have the link anymore) and reposting without answering the comments on the first one is not cool. It's throwing away the time people took to help you. As I already remember to say, you need to run Maven from the parent, it will build the modules in the correct order.

Comment: @Tunaki I answered to the comments but didn't get answers back. As regarding to your comment: what do you you mean by "*run Maven from the parent*"? I don't want to run Maven myself at all - I was hoping that Eclipse takes care for all of that as the code changes.

Comment: Do you have Workspace Resolution enabled? Right-click each Maven project and go to "Maven > Enable Workspace Resolution". Make sure they are updated also "Maven > Update Project".